# Laravel's @yield inside html tag for blade view engine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is this possible?

```
<html @yield( 'AngularNamespace' )>
</html>
```

Obviously the above doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me.

As long as your other template file has

```
@section('AngularNamespace', 'NameSpaceHere')
```

Comment: Was obviously some typo. sorry for wasting your time dude! Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

Its best to just pass a variable into your view, or create a view composer to bind the variable to that particular view.

**Controller:**

```
return View::make('myView', ['AngularNamespace' => $AngularNamespace]);
```

Or **View Composer:**

```
View::composer(['layouts.master'], function($view){

    $view->with('AngularNamespace', 'myNameSpace');

});
```

**View:**

```
<html {{ $AngularNamespace }} >
</html>
```